# Same command to copy directory in Windows as well as Mac

Tags: windows, macos, powershell, terminal, powershell-core

I want same command to copy directory in Windows as well as Mac. I don't want two different commands `cp` in terminal in Mac and `xcopy` in PowerShell in Windows. Is there a single command which can used in both Mac and Windows without any changes?

Comment: You could define aliases in both OS and just call it the same for both

Comment: Also, cp is already an alias for Copy-Item in Powershell...

Comment: The only way you could end up with identical operation on both computers would be to write your own scripts to handle one set of switches, and translate them to whichever operating system you are running it on. The two computers are using different operating systems, with different conventions for command switches, and different file systems that store different information differently. You'd be better off dealing with the differences and learning them.

Comment: You can use `cp -r` in both cases, since PowerShell has a built-in alias `cp` for `Copy-Item` and you can abbreviate parameters as long as the abbreviation remains unique. Note, however, that `Copy-Item` in PowerShell will ignore hidden files/folders unless you add the `-Force` switch. Besides, `xcopy` is more similar to `rsync` than to `cp` anyway. It's also not a native PowerShell command but an executable that can be used from PowerShell as well as CMD (or any other shell).

Comment: as long as this is tagged as 'powershell-core', I can't comprehend the question.  in Powershell Core for Mac & Windows the copy commands are exactly the same (Copy-Item ...)